# launch HTML code without opening web-browser

Tags: python, html

I have a device that can be managed with HTML codes

i would like to use python to pass these HTML codes to the device without having to open the web-browser, is there is a possible way?

```
import IEC

ie = IEC.IEController()       # Creates a new IE Window   "i want to skip this step"    
ie.Navigate('http://10.16.16.96/set?params=default')       # Navigate to a website.
```

Comment: JFTR: This is not HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2.x, Use [`urllib.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen):

```
import urllib
urlilb.urlopen('http://10.16.16.96/set?params=default').read()
```

In Python 3.x, use [`urllib.request.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen):

```
import urllib.request
urlilb.request.urlopen('http://10.16.16.96/set?params=default').read()
```

---

**UPDATE**

You can also use [`requests`](http://python-requests.org/) if you don't mind installing third party library:

```
import requests
requests.get('http://10.16.16.96/set?params=default').content
```

Comment: ... or use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org) without worrying about Python version differences.